# Hibernate: map objects into map with ids as keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a class with map inside. It is mapped with use of join table. I want object ids will be also keys for the map, so the it will be easier to found them. However when I try to define this in Hibernate-3.6.6, it creates additional column for keys in DB or just complains on duplicate mapping if I'm adding 'inverseJoinColumns'. Somebody knows how to solve this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sources")
@Lazy(false)
public class Sources {      
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )  
    @JoinTable( name = "sources_lists", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "list_id" ) )
    @MapKeyColumn( name = "source_id" )
    public Map<Integer, Source> getSources() { return sources; }
    public void setSources( Map<Integer, Source> sourcesList ) { this.adSources = adSourcesList; }
    private Map<Integer, Source> sources;

    @Override
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column( name="id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
    public Integer getId() { return super.getId(); }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: How to add new entities into map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406150/hibernate-how-to-add-new-entities-into-map)

Comment: No, Nicholas, it does not duplicate. Just two different issues caused by same piece of code. 
This question asks how to map Map without creating 3 different columns. 
The question you've marked as duplicate asks how to configure cascade on this map, in way that it will work with new un-persisted entities (id==null).
From my experience questions visitors even don't start to read questions marked as possible duplicates and it remains without answer.  Please read the question carefully before you do this.