# Hibernate: How to add new entities into map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to use map as property of the class, with ids as keys for easier retrieval. However, it is unclear how I can add new entities to a map, since new entities will have no id (id==null). It can work with one new object + cascade annotation, but sometimes there will be several new objects to add.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Sources")
@Lazy(false)
public class Sources {      
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )  
    @JoinTable( name = "sources_lists", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "list_id" ) )
    @MapKeyColumn( name = "source_id" )
    public Map<Integer, Source> getSources() { return sources; }
    public void setSources( Map<Integer, Source> sourcesList ) { this.adSources = adSourcesList; }
    private Map<Integer, Source> sources;

    @Override
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column( name="id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
    public Integer getId() { return super.getId(); }
}
```

Comment: One has to ask why you are trying to do what JPA is setup to do for you, and why wouldn't you have saved the entities before putting them into the map?

Comment: I agree with @Nicholas, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  If you have the ID of the Source and you want the source object wouldn't you just fetch the Source at that time?  It will be more performant than your approach (which would require two database queries).  If you plan on fetching all the sources in the map then you should just store a Set of Source objects instead of a map.

Comment: I do want that jpa will do the work. The code snippet post reads objects from db, as supposed. The problem is with something else. Considder the following scenario:  I want to add two new Source objects to existing map into Sources. Since it is new and it ate not in db their ids are null. If I'll put both of them into map and than save Sources the second one Source will override the first one and I'll actually save only one of them

Comment: I can pesist entities before adding them into map, but I try to understand if there is other way. I use Hibernate to make my life easier, and in most cases cascade do the work without forcing me to write additional saveIrUpdate queries.